# Referncing file locations in a php require

Tags: php

another easy question for someone!

on my server i have a location like

```
htdocs/aFolderName/
```

which contains a file index.php, which references a required file from

```
htdocs/aFolderName/php/
```

by using the code

```
<?php require('php/db.php'); ?>
```

I also have a folder

```
htdocs/aFolderName/other/
```

which contains another php file which needs to require the php file located

```
htdocs/aFolderName/php/
```

how do i reference this, can i step back a folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require('../otherfile.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require ('../php/yourFile.php');
```

:)

Relative pointers to directories:

`./` - current directory
`../` - parent directory

Answer (score 1):

.

```
require('./somefile.php'); // current directory
require('../somefile.php'); // one directory back
require('../../somefile.php'); // two directories back
require('../../../somefile.php'); // three directories back
// and on on...
```

I would suggest you to include your file by prefixing it with document root folder because sometimes if you don't specify that folder, file does not get included, so try like this:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . 'yourfolder/file.php');
```